# Should I worry about running out of HierarchyIDs?

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy, hierarchyid

When you ask for a new HierarchyID between two others, the result gets progressively longer.  For example, between 2/5.6 and 2/5.7 there's only 2/5.6.1 and other 4 component paths.  The HierarchyID data type is limited to 800 some bytes, so you can't repeat this forever.  Then again, integer types are also limited, but it isn't a problem in practice.  Should I periodically defragment my table so that height doesn't grow unbounded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's considered a "best practice" with the `hierarchyid` to "append" new IDs so that you don't use those in-between states (such as `/2/5.6/`) at all.  If your `hierarchyid` is a clustered primary key then that's bad for performance, it will cause page splits similar to the way a `uniqueidentifier` will.

If you generate *sequential* children, it's highly unlikely that you'd ever need to worry about running out; you can have literally millions of children for *each* parent.

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677212.aspx) is an example of how you're expected to generate `hierarchyid` values:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
    UPDATE Hierarchy
    SET @LastChild = LastChild = HId.GetDescendant(LastChild, NULL)
    WHERE HId = @ParentID

    INSERT Hierarchy (HId, ...)
    VALUES (@LastChild, ...)
COMMIT
```

If you generate the ids this way, rest assured you'll never have to worry about running out.

---

For curiosity's sake, I ran a quick test to find out for sure how deep you can go.  Here's a test script:

```
DECLARE
    @parent hierarchyid,
    @child hierarchyid,
    @high hierarchyid,
    @cnt int

SET @parent = '/1/'
SET @child = @parent.GetDescendant(NULL, NULL)
SET @cnt = 0

WHILE (@@ERROR = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1
    PRINT CAST(@cnt AS varchar(10)) + ': ' + @child.ToString()
    SET @high = @parent.GetDescendant(@child, @high)
    SET @child = @parent.GetDescendant(@child, @high)
END
```

You can see it error out at a point-nesting level of 1426, so that's your worst-case limit for how many "in-between" nodes you can create, *worst case* meaning that every single insertion goes in between the two most deeply-nested nodes.

As I mentioned in the comments, it's pretty hard to hit this limit, but that still doesn't make it a good idea to try.  The actual byte length gets longer as longer as you use up more and more "points", which degrades performance.  If the `hierarchyid` is your clustered index, this will *kill* performance by page splits.  If you're trying to rank nodes by parent then *use a ranking column* instead; it's easier *and* more efficient to sort from a later `SELECT` than it is to do during your `INSERT` where you have to worry about transaction isolation and other such headaches.

Comment: My application is maintaining rankings.  I actually have no need for slashes "/" in my paths.  Inserting between existing elements is key.

Comment: @Bruno: You really shouldn't think of `hierarchyid` as a way of maintaining a specific ordering of children.  Yes it's *capable* of doing that, but it's not *optimized* for that case at all.  If you want rankings, then add a ranking column.  (P.S. I'm not sure what you mean when you say you have no need for slashes - there aren't *actual* "slashes" in a `hierarchyid`, that's just the string representation.)

Comment: What type do you suggest to use for rankings, allowing insertion between any pair?

Comment: @Bruno: What is the actual criteria for ranking them?  Use that, or compute some integral score out of it.  Why do you need to make this into an insertion problem (complicated) as opposed to a sorting problem (easy)?

Comment: Anyway, you can use the `hierarchyid` for it if you really want, it's pretty hard to run into a practical limit with "point" ids, but it tends to hurt performance if you do it too much, especially if the `hierarchyid` is your clustered index.