# Error 24000 when trying to use hierarchyid

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, hierarchyid

I am having issues when I try and generate `hierarchyid` in my application. Specifically, I cannot seem to have more than 16 children per node. Here is the code that I am trying to use for my stored proc (this is for a test table that just has an hid field, and a content field:

```
create PROC testAdd (@parentid hierarchyid, @content varchar(10)) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
       @parentNode hierarchyid , 
       @lc hierarchyid;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    SELECT @lc = MAX (hid)
      FROM testing
      WHERE hid.GetAncestor (1) = @parentid;

    INSERT INTO testing (hid, content) 
    VALUES ( @parentid.GetDescendant(@lc, NULL),
    @content) ;
    COMMIT;
END;
```

Here is how I get an error:

1. Run `INSERT INTO testing (hid , content) 
   VALUES (hierarchyid::GetRoot () , 'a') ;`
2. Run `EXEC testAdd '/' , 'a';` 16 times.

The error I get looks like: 
[image]

Additionally, I attempted to run the second code snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2840507/725709), and it broke immediately.

What could be going wrong?

**Update:** I have already uninstalled VS 2015, and the CLR data types for sql server 2014 and replaced them with an older version to no avail.

Comment: FWIW I can run the EXEC testAdd more than 16 times with no error. Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2000.8 (X64) Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )

Comment: @ClintGood I think it has something to to with the fact that I installed VS 2015 preview. What is the version of the Types assembly?

Comment: microsoft.sqlserver.types, version=12.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorarchitecture=msil

Comment: @ClintGood is there a way to see what assembly the hierarchyid type is coming from?

Comment: I just ran select * from sys.assemblies

Comment: @ClintGood is there anything else that can mess with the type (I get the exact same thing as you)

Comment: I would try each part individually. `set @parentid = '/' select @lc = max(hid)...` and see which line it is dying on.

Comment: @ClintGood The simpler sample (from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840476/should-i-worry-about-running-out-of-hierarchyids/2840507#2840507) second code snipped) shows it breaks on ToString

Comment: @ClintGood https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/1063935/visual-studio-2015-breaks-hierarchyid-clr-type